# x11vnc server creates multiple screens

Tags: xorg, vnc

So this picture is showing the problem with scaling turned on.
I'm only connecting to 5900 (display 0) and there's just one user.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivF4q.jpg

It's super slow so why does it do it and how do I make it just share the main screen?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got the same issue, using both JumpDesktop and Apple ScreenSharing